# What are analytics variable names?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, bookmarklet

I have set custom variables in Google Analytics call and they are working fine.

I want to make it easier for users to see what Custom variables are set on a page so they don't have to look at the source code. They'll be using the values set to filter custom reports in Google Analytics.

So the idea was to write a bookmarklet to show the value set.

**My problem is I cannot find the name of the variable the value is being stored in.**

This is not the Custom Variable name itself.

I've looked at the Analytics API, used gatest.js in Chrome and inspected the tracking GIF.

What I want to show in an alert is the data from:

```
Custom Var 5: label:'MenuIDs' value:'xxx' scope:'Page'
```

I assume its something like:

```
utme or _utme
```

Apologies for such a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the google analytics debugger shows that the utme parameter in the gif contains custom variable labels in some kind of encoded format.

In my site it shows:

utme=8(2![CVlabel1]*[CVlabel2]*[CVlabel3])9(2![CVvalue1]*[CVvalue2]*[CVvalue3])11(4!1)

where [CVlabelX] and [CVvalueX] is where my CV data appeared.

Hope that helps